# Gap around textarea within a table

Tags: css, textarea

I've done some research on removing the gap I've got around a textarea located in a table. Depending on the browser, it appears at the top (IE, Chrome) or bottom (Firefox).

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
         <form method="POST" action="updatereview.php">
              <td class="shrink">
                  text
              </td>
              <td class="shrink">
                   <select name='update_score'>
                       <option  value="1">1</option>
                       <option  value="2">2</option>
                       <option  value="3">3</option>
                   </select>
                   <input type="textbox" name="new_retailer">
              </td>
              <td class="one-long-line">
                   <div id="content" style="width:100%;">
                       <textarea name="review_comment" rows="10" style="resize:none;">some text here</textarea>
                   </div>                   
              </td>
         </form>          
     </tr>
</table>
```

I've not included all my CSS here as there's lots of it, but I've put it all in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xmx2dex/1/ CSS for textarea is right at the end.

After doing some research, adding "vertical-align: top;" to my CSS should have solved this, but to no avail. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `table tr:nth-child(odd) td` rule change `vertical-align: text-top;` to `vertical-align: top;`

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9xmx2dex/2/)**

Comment: Knew it would be something simple I'd missed; thanks so much!